# Cannot get CR and LF to display

Tags: masm32

I'm trying to display the carriage return and line feed in my code but it does not work. If I print out the codes as a string it works. Help needed. Thanks in advance.

;  A 16-bit DOS program that receives a single char from STDIN and then prints it out to ;STDOUT

```
    .MODEL small
    .stack 100h

    .data

    char_prompt     db  'Please input a character: ','$'
    out_msg1        db  'Character entered is: ','$'
    out_msg2         db 0dh,0ah, '$'    

    .code
    start:

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax ; Set DS segment

    mov dx, offset char_prompt; display msg1
    mov ah,9    
    int 21h    

    mov ah, 01h ;store char in BL
    int     21h
    mov bl, al

    mov dl, 0dh; ;output CR
    mov ah, 02h  
    int 21

    mov dl, 0ah ;output LF
    mov ah, 02h
    int 21

    mov dx, offset out_msg1 ;display msg2
    mov ah,9
    int 21h    

    mov     dl, bl ;display char  
    mov     ah, 02h  
    int 21h

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h

    end start
```

Comment: Wow! just wow, in 2012, in this day and age, someone using masm and 16bit DOS... just bloody wow! Have to upvote this question as its a blast in the past but gunner beat me to it... :D

Comment: As a redditor, the oft-said expression that appears in a particular sub-reddit, "*That's enough internet for me today...*" LOL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is wrong:
Look carefully at the int parts:

```
mov dl, 0dh; ;output CR
mov ah, 02h  
int 21

mov dl, 0ah ;output LF
mov ah, 02h
int 21
```

What are you missing? INT 21 is NOT correct!!  It should be INT 21H

Comment: ahh fcek.... you're bloody right there mate! int 21h... ffffuuuu... /me facepalms

Comment: You could do int 33 if you wanted to since it is the same as 21H only in decimal

Comment: @Gunner thanks for the reply. You guys are sharp !!! I just missed that and yep I know the difference between decimal and hexadecimal for the value of 21. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
mov ah, 06h
mov dl, 0dh ; CR
int 21h

mov ah, 06h
mov dl, 0ah ; LF
int 21h
```

Have to say this, this is a blast from the past... :)

Had to go to my favorite site [Ralf Brown](http://www.ctyme.com/rbrown.htm)'s [Interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2558.htm)... to remember what was the instruction for the direct console output..

***Edit:*** as per Gunner pointed out.. yeah the 'h' is missing.. am too bloody old... :P He deserved the upvotes etc :)